# Customize title of beamer note pages

Tags: beamer, presentations, frame-title, pgfpages

I'd like to customize the title area of the note pages for a `beamer` document. I've changed the background/foreground colors of `note title` and `note page` respectively, and intend to keep them that way (in this example).

In addition, I'd like to remove from the note page the date, *slides* title, and footnote associated with the title (on the corresponding slide, if any). I'd also want to remove the thumbnail image of the slide on the right. Finally, I want to move the *slide* title on the note page (along with section title(s), if any, up to two so possibly 'section' and 'subsection') up so that the title area takes less vertical space (maybe still slightly taller than the title area of the corresponding slide).

Currently this is what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
    \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}
\makeatother

\setbeamersize{text margin left=7mm,text margin right=7mm}
\usetheme[sectionpage=progressbar,subsectionpage=progressbar,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[infolines]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamercolor{note title}{bg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=green}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\scriptsize}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\scriptsize}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\tiny}}{}

\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\title{Slides Title}
\author{Autho Name}
\institute{Author Affiliation}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Slide Title\footnote{Some footnote}}
    Some text in the main slides
\end{frame}

\note{
    Some notes
}
%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

And with annotations to show what I want (and obviously the changes also apply to other pages, incl. the first title page):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a footnote to the title of a slide, use also the optional parameter of `\frametitle` to define the title (without the footnote) used in toc and in notes page:

```
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle[Title used in toc and in notes]%
   {Title used in frame\footnote{with a footnote}}
\end{frame}
```

### To customize the note page

In the following code, I defined the `custom` option for `note page` template by copying the `default` predefined option (from `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`) and commenting on the useless code.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
    \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}

\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{custom}
{%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \usebeamerfont{note title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{note title}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note title}{}{%
      \insertvrule{.25\paperheight}{note title.bg}%
      \vskip-.25\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip%
    }%
    \vbox{
      %\hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.25}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%
      %\vskip-0.25\paperheight%
      %\nointerlineskip
      % \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
      %   \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformrotate{90}}
      %     {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.2cm}}%
      %       \pgftext[base,left]{\usebeamerfont{note date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{note date}\the\year-\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month-\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day}}
      %   \end{pgflowlevelscope}
      % \end{pgfpicture}
    }
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to .25\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
      %\hbox{\insertshorttitle[width=0.75\textwidth]}%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.71\textwidth}\def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.71\textwidth}\def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=0.67\textwidth]}\fi%
      }%
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note page}{}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \insertvrule{.75\paperheight}{note page.bg}%
    \vskip-.75\paperheight%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \insertnote
}
\makeatother

\setbeamersize{text margin left=7mm,text margin right=7mm}
\usetheme[sectionpage=progressbar,subsectionpage=progressbar,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}


\setbeamertemplate{note page}[custom]

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamercolor{note title}{fg=orange!75!black,bg=orange!10}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{fg=green!50!black,bg=green!10}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\scriptsize}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\scriptsize}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\tiny}}{}

\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\title{Global Title}
\author{Author Name}
\institute{Author Affiliation}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle[Slide Title]{Slide Title\footnote{Some footnote}}
    Some text in the main slides
\end{frame}

\note{
    Some notes
}
%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

### Full width titles (and adjustable proportion)

Here is a new version with full width titles. This new `custom` option for `note page` template uses an optional parameter to specify the proportion (by default `.25`) of `\paperheight` used to insert titles. In my example, I use `.3` (since my example uses very very long titles). If your slides use short titles, you can try `.2` or `.15`...

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
    \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}

\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{custom}[1][.25] % #1: proportion of \paperheight for titles (default: 0.25)
{%
  \def\beamercustomnotepageproptitle{#1}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\beamercustomnotepagepropnotes{1-\beamercustomnotepageproptitle}%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \usebeamerfont{note title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{note title}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note title}{}{%
      \insertvrule{\beamercustomnotepageproptitle\paperheight}{note title.bg}%
      \vskip-\beamercustomnotepageproptitle\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to \beamercustomnotepageproptitle\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4pt-.4pt-9pt-1pt}%
            \def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-17.4pt-.4pt-9pt-1pt}%
            \def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-30.8pt-.4pt-9pt-1pt]}\fi%
      }%
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note page}{}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \insertvrule{\beamercustomnotepagepropnotes\paperheight}{note page.bg}%
    \vskip-\beamercustomnotepagepropnotes\paperheight%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \insertnote
}
\makeatother

\setbeamersize{text margin left=7mm,text margin right=7mm}
\usetheme[sectionpage=progressbar,subsectionpage=progressbar,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}


\setbeamertemplate{note page}[custom][.3]

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamercolor{note title}{fg=orange!75!black,bg=orange!10}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{fg=green!50!black,bg=green!10}
\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\scriptsize}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\scriptsize}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\tiny}}{}

\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\title{Global Title}
\author{Author Name}
\institute{Author Affiliation}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First section with very very very very very very vvery very very very very very very very long title}
\subsection{First subsection with very very very very v v v very very very very very very very very long title}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle[Very Very Very Very Very Very v Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long Slide Title As Short Title]
  {Slide Title\footnote{Some footnote}}

  Some text in the main slides
\end{frame}

\note{
    Some notes
}
%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how can we make the title area (light orange in your example) vertically shorter given now we only need to show up to three layers of titles?

Comment: And it seems the width of the titles is limited as if the space for the thumbnail image is reserved on the right, so a long title may cause a line break before reaching the right end of the whole title area. How can we make the hierarchical titles take the whole width of the orange title area?

Comment: @Skyork I added an improved version of my `custom` option.

Comment: It works great! Just curious, when I `\begin{frame}{Slide Title\footnote{Some footnote}}` the footnote still appears in the title area on the note page, but when I adopt your `\begin{frame}\frametitle[Slide Title]{Slide Title\footnote{Some footnote}}` it no longer shows, why is this the case?

Comment: @Skyork In the first case, the footnote is attached to the title and it appears wherever the title is inserted. In the second case, the optional parameter defines the title used in the toc and in the note page.